# Ignoring .htaccess files and rules in one subdirectory via Apache .conf file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get Apache to ignore .htaccess files and rules in one subdirectoy (and all of its subsequent directories), but still allow them to execute in the parent, root directory. It seems like this works:

```
<Directory /home/user/test_domain_com/www/test>
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

However, the problem here is that if there is an .htaccess file in the root folder with certain rules, the subdirectoy will still be affected. (e.g., call test.php upon any request):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php [L]
```

This example still affects the directory that I want to ignore .htaccess rules on. Is it possible to not just ignore .htaccess files inside of this directory, but also ignore any .htaccess rules that may apply this directoy as well? Is there something I can add to the .conf file to accomplish this?

I hope that made sense.

Thanks

Comment: Try adding a .htaccess file to your subdirectory and just put this line at the top `RewriteEngine off`

Comment: I have the subdirectoy ignoring .htaccess files already. What I'm really trying to accomplish is avoiding inherited .htaccess rules from its parent directoy.

Comment: Also, in my actual production scenario, I have to accomplish this through the .conf file. I can't add to already existing .haccess files. I want to simply ignore them without modifying them.

Comment: Ok, I noticed the directory and file are the same name. Is that the case? Is the directory the same name as the php file? That will cause a conflict.

Comment: No, that was just an arbitrary example.  I just want one directory `x` to ignore any .htaccess rules that might interfere with it, whether those are .htaccess files are within the `x` folder or whether they are rules in the parent folder that might affect folder `x`. I want the .conf file to see that folder `x` is an actual directory and prevent applying any re-write rules to it.

Answer (score 0):

From https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

> ```
> Only available in <Directory> sections
> AllowOverride is valid only in <Directory> sections specified without regular expressions, not in <Location>, <DirectoryMatch> or
> ```
>
> sections.

I suggest updating to:

```
<Directory "/home/user/test_domain_com/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/user/test_domain_com/www/test">
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I typed "Location." It actually is already set to Directory, which works, but not fully what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I essentially already have what you suggested. Rules in an .htaccess in the www directoy will still apply to the test directoy, depending on what the rules are. I want the test directoy to ignore any parent folder's .htaccess rules as well.

Comment: Oh, that makes a difference. Have you considered moving the top level .htaccess entirely into Apache config? It's a good practice, improves response times and strengthens security.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do that. This is a third-party app not developed by me. There are several .htaccess files in the parent directories I'd have to account for. Plus, on updating the app, I'm sure it'd break something.